# Google Uploading Issue with the same Keystore file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I met strange thing to upload my apk on Google Store.
I needed to upgrade my app so I rebuild APK with the same keystore file which was used in last one.
But I got this issue. This is unity project.
[image]

I checked all build settings including short bundle version and build version on Unity Editor, but I couldn`t find the strange thing.
I upgraded build version and short bundle version and tried to upload APK on Google Store, but I got the same issue.
How Can I solve this problem?
Please let me know what the cause of this issue is.

Answer (score 1):

The SHA1 hash for the two applications are technically different. So there are really only two options:

1. You are actually signing the APK with the wrong key. I would run a quick SHA-1 over what you think is the signing key to verify before doing anything else.
2. This is the LEAST likely. Something is wrong with your signing setup - I don't know how you produce artifacts (CI, manually, etc) but you could always try signing your APK manually without any tools to verify it isn't the problem of something else https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Being blunt, 1 is much more likely than 2. So I would first start checking the hashes of other *.jks files you have nearby before venturing down the path of verify tool correctness.

Comment: Thanks. But this was for Unity. I think you mentioned about Eclipse Project. Then do you have any good suggestion?

Comment: You are still producing an Android APK, the build process should be similar no matter what environment you are in.

Unity's development environment may do some extra stuff for you that I don't have the expertise to tell you about. I don't develop in Unity for any projects, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a different keystore. There is sometimes a keystore for debugging, and a keystore for the release. Ensure you're not using the incorrect one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked keystore file again, but it was the same one which was used on last build. and I checked alias item on Build Settings/Publish Settings, but it was correct. I made this keystore for releasing my app. Please tell me more details.

Comment: the different fingerprint shows it's a different keystore :( hate to be a buzz kill. maybe you wrote over the previous one by mistake. I was lucky to find mine again once, then I realised how important it is to keep safe

Comment: I used same keystore, not previous one. So I think it is very strange.